# How do I use zc.buildout and setup.py together?

Tags: python, package, buildout, setup.py

I use zc.buildout to develop my project and download dependencies (use-site-packages is `off`).

I want to install my project as a package on a target system before running it. For that I make setup.py.

Do I need to repeat the list of dependencies in setup.py again?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`zc.buildout` *relies* on your package setup.py, so if your package has dependencies, list those in the `setup.py` `install_requires` list.

Only list those dependencies in your buildout configuration to pin the versions in a `versions` section.

So, installing a simple egg `foo` that depends on `bar` and `baz`:

```
[buildout]
parts = foo

[foo]
recipe = zc.recipe.egg
eggs = foo
```

where `setup.py` for the `foo` egg has a `install_dependencies = ['bar', 'baz']` entry. Buildout will take care of installing `bar` and `baz` for you, without those explicitly being listed.

Pinning version numbers:

```
[buildout]
parts = foo
versions = versions

[foo]
recipe = zc.recipe.egg
eggs = foo

[versions]
foo = 1.2.1
bar = 0.2
baz = 3.0b1
```